# facebook like args on URL - why forbidden?

Tags: facebook, apache, facebook-like

Running Apache with a html file for the index - it works fine when I tap into the browser:

```
http://mywebsite.com
```

but if someone clicks through from my facebook activity feed, the link is similar:

```
http://mywebsite.com/?fb_action_ids=10151583105966609&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B"10151583105966609"%3A10150220203269128%7D&action_type_map=%7B"10151583105966609"%3A"og.likes"%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D
```

...but it doesn't work - chrome returns

```
Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

My question is why does it come back forbidden?  Surely it is merely the args that have changed?

I am not looking for a solution to clean up the URL, but rather to understand why supplying these URL args returns "forbidden".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, and it is related to the 5G-blacklist-2013 I was using in my .htaccess which I didn't think was relevant initially - in retrospect, where else was I going to find the problem?  Silly me.

The blocklist contains the line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
```

...as part of its test for illegal query strings.  The query string that facebook appends when clicking through from the activity feed falls foul of this line and a 403 is returned.  To fix I can either remove that line or strip the query string earlier in the .htaccess.

5g-blacklist-2013: http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/

Comment: I've let the maintainer of the 5g blacklist know.